# Как исправить ошибку записи в БД после соединения двух таблиц?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Как бы я не выставлял в ON UPDATE и ON DELETE при соединеии таблиц, все равно при добавлении в таблицу add_photos_store данных через админку, такая ошибка "

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`freeman_domolux`.`add_photos_store`, CONSTRAINT
>   `add_photos_store_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`magazin_id`) REFERENCES
>   `stores` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

" это я перевожу "Невозможно добавить или обновить дочернюю строку: ограничение внешнего ключа не выполняется" ограничения я не ставил, почему такая ошибка? Но зато через phpmyadmin инфу можно вставить в add_photos_store и там я выбираю при вставке id магазина, все отображается но все одинаковое в каждом магазине, это из за выборки. Нужно писать выборку так select * from add_photos_store where magazin_id = n, где n - id магазина т.е magazin_id = id но вылазит такая ошибка "Unknown column 'magazin_id' in 'where clause'". Что не так делаю?

Comment: on delete выполняется при удалении, on update соответственно при изменении. А вот при вставке данных в родительской таблице обязана быть запись, на которую ссылается вставляемая дочерняя. Перед вставкой дочерней записи убедитесь, что вы заносите в поле такую ID, которая уже есть в родительской

Comment: а почему не находит колонку сказать сложно, какая нибудь ошибка в одной букве или может структура таблицы отличается от того что на картинке

Comment: Посмотрю, вот БД http://dropmefiles.com/jtivv может она поможет с ответом.

Comment: Что бы записать в дочернюю, нужно создать магазин, иначе кнопки не появится, поэтому я добавляю в дочернюю уже когда родительская создана.

Comment: Ну на этой БД запрос `select * from add_photos_store where magazin_id=1` завершается без ошибок. так что где то у себя смотрите, может phpmyadmin или через что вы запрос выполняете коннектится к какой то другой БД

Comment: Вы приведите в вопросе все insert которые пишите. в родительскую, потом в дочернюю

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/67ac10fc43a35c44a7fbd1383822dd1451cd9a34 здесь 3 небольших куска кода, я их прокомментировал. Думаю в них что то не так. Не подскажете что не так?

Comment: Во первых _никогда_ не пишите `select *`. _Всегда_ явно перечисляйте те колонки, которые хотите получить. У вас в запросе 2 таблицы в обоих из которых есть столбец `id`. Я не берусь предсказать id из какой таблицы будет доступен через `$add_photo['id']`

Comment: Во вторых _никогда_ не подставляйте полученные параметры в текст запроса. Используйте mysqli/pdo и привязываемые переменные. http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать.